# installing android x86 in a virtual machine

Tags: vmware-workstation, android-x86

I am following the instructions given [HERE](http://xmodulo.com/2013/02/how-to-install-and-run-android-vm-on-vmware-player.html)
I can install it to the vmware hard disk fine and get it running, but then it says to open a terminal and execute su
The terminal says that it cannot make me a root and nothing else
I am not able to go any further after this and so the internet isn't working in the virtual machine
Moreover, the internet works if I was just using the live CD version, without me having to do anything else
How do I get root permissions in android x86 on VMware?

--- EDIT---

After playing around some more with this I have noticed another problem: when I try to start the virtual machine, most of the times it reaches the Chrome coloured android startup logo, the logo animates continuously but the screen is sort of stuck at that phase. And if I loose focus to the vmware window and come back, I see that the window is blank and I am not sure if the virtual machine is even further loading or not. How do I properly get Android x86 to work on vmware (with full install on it's virtual hard disk and not just the live CD version? Should I try other virtual machines? I have not been able to get others such as qemu and bochs to work in the past and see that vmware is the easiest and most stable option, so I would like to run this in vmware if possible.

Answer (score 0):

check here www.bitdirect.nl/?p=128

I followed this with a few little tweaks here and there and it worked perfectly.

only downside is transferring data outside of the android os is a pain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.